# My Rails app doesn't like my attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and Ruby and actually it's my first web language. This isn't my first project but it's the bigest so far and I am having trouble with a certain page (the "home" page).

The error is:

```
NoMethodError in Home#index undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
2: <ul>
3:   <li><b>Name:</b><%= current_user.name %></li>
4:   <li><b>Username:</b><%= current_user.username %></li>
```

So it doesn't like my attributes :( What should I do in this situation? Where should I look first? Is this a controller problem?

Comment: def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `current_user` is returning `nil`.

Take a look at the error

```
NoMethodError in Home#index undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

Ruby is saying that you are trying to execute an instance method `avatar` on the `nil` object. After looking at your code, you should be able to tell that you are calling `avatar` on the return value of `current_user` so you can deduce that `current_user` is returning `nil` instead of the user.

**Per the comments:**

To solve this you will need to first determine if there is a `current_user`. Then and only then do you try to display a users `avatar` or the users other attributes (`name`, `username` ...)

Some people do not like logic in the views, I tend to follow this practice.

To avoid this, you could: create a view helper that contains the logic. This helper may or may not display/return data about a user.

Something along the lines of `if current_user ...`

Comment: The solution would be to wrap that code in an `<% if current_user.present? %>`, so that it doesn't throw errors if there's no logged in user.

Comment: `<% if current_user %>` should be enough.

Comment: I would recommend removing the logic of whether or not to display the current_users avatar to a view helper, given that there may or may not be a current user.  Therefore, in the view code, there would be a  `display_avatar` view helper that would determine whether or not to show anything.  This would keep the view code clean from logic code.

Comment: @PeterDegen-Portnoy, then the code below will start failing... I don't think there's anything wrong with simple if statements like this in the view.

Comment: @Kyle, yeah `<% if current_user %>` would work too. Adding a `logged_in?` method to the ApplicationController may be even better. Anyway, maybe you could add the solution to the problem to your answer...

Comment: Sorry for nagging, but if you create a helper for the avatar, `current_user.name` and `current_user.username` will start failing. Or will you create helpers for that too? Just use a simple if statement in the view... at least that's my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the avatar for the 'current_user'.  The system is complaining because it doesn't know who or what current_user is.

Your current_user object is nil.  The code causing the problem (probably form your application or sessions helper) where you are setting the current_user...is most likely where you'll find the root of the problem.